# How to use regex to extract data from bank statement?

Tags: regex

I have the following fake lines:

```
CITECH CO., 2019043000193299 CITECH CO.,LT CITECH CO.,LTD USD 1000

YAMAHA MUSIC 665FGMPE175486L YAMAHA MUSIC M YAMAHA MUSIC MANUFACTURING ASIA, USD 1000.95

CONTINENTAL AUT 1599875156FA CONTINENTAL AUTOM CONTINENTAL AUTOMOTIVE ROMANIA SRL USD 2000.1

CONTINENTAL A X0691580D3E601 CONTINENTAL AUT CONTINENTAL AUTOMOTIVE COMP (I) P L USD 2000.55
```

How can I extract the company name after the codes, like after

```
2019043000193299?
```

and also the dollar amounts after USD?

I don't even know how to start.

Comment: You need to define a rule of how the information is structured, and from that structure how the information is to be extracted, and be able to solve it manually, applying that rule. Only after that, you can do it programmatically (regex or something else).

Comment: The downvotes mean "you study regex syntax"

Comment: you're going to get down voted here. go over to regex101.com and take a few stabs at it. Read the documentation on the common tokens. Then edit with an example of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer by myself:

```
^([A-Z]*)\s([0-9A-Z]*)\s([A-Z0-9]*)\s(FX:1)\s(.+?)(\w{12,16})\s(.+?)(USD)\s(\d+\.?\d*)
```